# Update CSS class based on value in model after Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a view where I display a list of episodes. I'm using a partial for that:

```
    <div class="episode-list">
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= render partial: "shared_partials/episode_with_image_compact", collection: @recent_episodes, as: :episode %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

In that partial I have a button_to that sends a request to the backend to mark an episode as seen:

```
          <%= button_to manual_new_scrobble_path, {method: :post, form_class: 'manual-scrobble-btn', class: "button is-small #{'listened' if episode.has_play}", remote: true, params: {scrobble: {user_id: current_user.id, episode_id: episode.id}}} do %>
            <%= scrobble_icon(episode) %>
          <% end %>
```

The `scrobble_icon` function just sets a class based on the status of an episode like this:

```
  def scrobble_icon(episode)
    if episode.has_play
      icon('fas', 'check', class: 'listened')
    else
      icon('fas', 'check', class: 'unlistened')
    end
  end
```

I'm using `remote: true` so it doesn't result in a page load. When I was doing other frontend frameworks for SPA there was always this two-way-binding by default where the value would update based on the status of the "store" / model.

I've now read multiple articles about [TurboLinks](https://medium.com/@jmanrubia/escaping-the-spa-rabbit-hole-with-turbolinks-903f942bf52c) and [server generated javascript](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3697-server-generated-javascript-responses) but I still can't figure out what's the correct solution to the problem.

What I want:

- Click on button
- Request is successful and writes value to DB
- Button now has the class "listened"

What actually happens:

- Click on button
- Request is successful and writes value to DB
- Button looks the same
- I reload the page, button now has the class "listened"

A lot of answers to similar problems talk about jQuery which is:

1) not in Rails 6 any more
2) not something I want to use in 2019

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end what I had to do was to add a class as mentioned in [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod)'s answer but the building block I didn't understand in my previous reply is the following.

In your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` (or a custom one if you prefer) you have to set up a listener on the `ajax:success` event that gets emmited by Rails as mentioned in the [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript).

Then we have to check for our unique `id` in the event to differentiate events coming from other sources. We then add / remove the classes and everything works as expected.

So far it seems to work fine, if there's something I missed please let me know!

```
document.addEventListener('ajax:success', function (event) {
    let detail = event.detail;
    let data = detail[0], status = detail[1], xhr = detail[2];

    // Check if our event is from an manual episode scrobble button
    let button = [...event.target.children].find(element => element.id === 'scrobble_btn_episode' + data.episode_id);

    // If find() is not successful it's undefined
    if (typeof button !== 'undefined') {
        // We set the classes on our button
        button.classList.add("listened");
        button.classList.remove("unlistened");

        // The button has a child, we also set the classes there for the check mark
        let id = button.getElementsByClassName('fa-check');
        id[0].classList.add("listened");
        id[0].classList.remove("unlistened");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to render a javascript script that:
1 - finds the element
2 - updates it's class

First I would add some identifier so you can identify the correct button

```
<%= button_to manual_new_scrobble_path, {method: :post, form_class: 'manual-scrobble-btn', class: "button is-small #{'listened' if episode.has_play}", id: "button_for_episode_#{episode.id}", remote: true, params: {scrobble: {user_id: current_user.id, episode_id: episode.id}}} do %>
  <%= scrobble_icon(episode) %>
<% end %>
```

Note the `id: "button_for_episode_#{episode.id}" parameter

Now you can target this with something like:

```
// find the button
let button = document.getElementById("button_for_episode_#{params[:scobble][:episode_id]}");
// add the class
button.classList.add('listened');

// find the icon within that button
let icon = button.querySelector('.fas');
// remove "unlistened" class
icon.classList.remove('unlistened');
// add "listened" class
icon.classList.add('listened');
```

This script should be the view for the action you are calling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there were some other things that were unclear to make it more re-useable. Posted my own approach, let me know if you see any issues with that!